# Converting numeric array to associative array using implode or explode?

Tags: php, arrays, explode, implode

So lets say I have an array and when I `var_dump();` it, it has the following output:

```
[1]=>
string(20) "Name:          Kevin"
[2]=>
string(20) "Age:              20"
```

Can I manipulate it using implode or explode so that the output would look like this:

```
[Name]=>
string(5) "Kevin"
[Age]=>
string(2) "20"
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `explode()` with `trim()`

```
$array = [];

foreach($initialArray as $data){
    $exploded = explode(':',$data);
    $array[trim($exploded[0])] = trim($exploded[1]);
}
```

Output:-https://3v4l.org/3q0i5

Comment: This has worked perfectly, thank you. i was not sure you could use explode like that.

Comment: @Tenka  glad to help you.